# Random Forest Error (input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples)

Tags: python, random-forest, feature-selection

After reading so many examples with 'inconsistent number of samples' errors, I am still not able to see what is wrong with my code.

In an excel file, sheet 1 contains data. Sheet 2 contains a shortlisted list of variables.

I saved the variables in sheet 2 into an array. And feed it to a Random Forest model to evaluate its impact on a parameter in sheet 1.

But I am getting "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [54, 2016]"

54 is the number of variables in sheet 2. 
2016 is the number of rows of data in sheet 1.

I am trying to see how these 54 variables impact 'Target' variable in sheet 1.

How should i manipulate my data to make this work?

Many thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\ngks\Desktop\TP Course\Project Module\ProjectDataSetrev2.xlsx',sheet_name=0)
df2 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\ngks\Desktop\TP Course\Project Module\ProjectDataSetrev2.xlsx',sheet_name=1)

df['DateTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['Time Stamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df.set_index(df['DateTime'], inplace=True)

print(len(df2.columns))

allvar = list()

for each_var in df2.columns:
    allvar.append(each_var)

allvar = np.array(allvar)
print(allvar)

target = df['(CUP) Chiller Optimization Plant Efficiency [kW/RT]']
target=target.values.reshape(len(target),1)

allvar_train,allvar_test,target_train,target_test= train_test_split(allvar,target, random_state=0, test_size=0.6)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10000, random_state=0, n_jobs=-1)

clf.fit(allvar_train, target_train)

for feature in zip(feat_labels, clf.feature_importances_):
    print(feature)
```

Sheet 1 (saved as df) looks like this
[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gASnp.jpg)

Sheet 2 (saved as df2) looks like this
[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01byX.jpg)

Error log is as shown
[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpnUX.jpg)

Error log 2: Unknown label type: 'continuous'[Error Log 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdVOO.jpg)

[allvar_train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrWKE.jpg)

[target train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZKpI.jpg)

Comment: Please, share the entire error log.

Comment: Screenshot of error log added to the main post. Thanks Ayush.

Comment: The Variable 'allvar' is just the names of columns, it doesn't have the data. That's why the shape is different. 'allvar' has 54 rows(only column names) while target has 2016 rows( data). You need to pass feature data and target data in "train_test_split"

Comment: Error is with "train_test_split" which is nothing to do with Random Forest.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the code that works for me.

```
  import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
    from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

    df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\ngks\Desktop\TP Course\Project Module\ProjectDataSetrev3.xlsx',sheet_name=0)
    df2 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\ngks\Desktop\TP Course\Project Module\ProjectDataSetrev3.xlsx',sheet_name=1)

    df['DateTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['Time Stamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df.set_index(df['DateTime'], inplace=True)

    print(len(df2.columns))

    allvarlist = list()

    for each_var in df2.columns:
        allvarlist.append(each_var)

    countvar = len(allvarlist)

    allvar = df[allvarlist]
    allvar = allvar.values.reshape(len(allvar),countvar)

    target = df['(CUP) Chiller Optimization Plant Efficiency [kW/RT]']
    target=target.values.reshape(len(target),1)

    allvar_train,allvar_test,target_train,target_test= train_test_split(allvar,target, random_state=0, test_size=0.7)

    clf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=10000, random_state=0, n_jobs=-1)

    #print(allvar_train)
    #print(target_train)

    clf.fit(allvar_train,np.ravel(target_train))

    for feature in zip(allvarlist, clf.feature_importances_):
        print(feature)

    importances = clf.feature_importances_
    #indices = np.argsort(importances)

    plt.figure().set_size_inches(14,16)
    plt.barh(range(allvar_train.shape[1]), importances, color="r")
    plt.yticks(range(allvar_train.shape[1]),allvarlist)
```

Comment: It's a bad practice to write questions in the answer section. It is better to edit the question accordingly or post another question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with 'train_test_spilt', where you're only passing the feature column name not the data. Use the list of columns to get data from the DataFrame like this.

```
allvar_train,allvar_test,target_train,target_test= train_test_split(df[allvar],target, random_state=0, test_size=0.6)
```

You don't necessarily need to convert 'allvar' and 'target' to numpy array it can directly be used in 'train_test_split'.

Note: This issue  has got nothing to do with Random Forest

Comment: I managed to solved the problems and have successfully plotted a chart on Feature Importance. Thanks Ayush for your help.

Comment: I have posted my codes on the main post for reference.